# New DbContext vs. constructor injection of DbContext in WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, dependency-injection

In a WPF app, what is really the benefit of using constructor injection of a database context compared to new:ing up a new instance in, for example a using block?

Please see the two examples below. They both work as intended, but which one is better - and why?

**Example 1: New Instance of AppDbContext**

*MainWindow*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        using (AppDbContext context = new AppDbContext())
        {
            var people = context.People.ToList();
            // Do stuff with people
        }
    }
}
```

*AppDbContext*

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    public AppDbContext()
    {

    }

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer({DB_CONNECTION_STRING});

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Example 2: Constructor Injection with AppDbContext**

*MainWindow*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly AppDbContext context;

    public MainWindow(AppDbContext context)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.context = context;

        var people = context.People.ToList();
        // Do stuff with people
   }
}
```

*App.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static IHost? AppHost { get; private set; }

    public App()
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();

        AppHost = builder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => 
                options.UseSqlServer({DB_CONNECTION_STRING}));
        }).Build();
    }

    protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        await AppHost!.StartAsync();

        AppHost.Services.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>().Show();

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }

    protected override async void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        await AppHost!.StopAsync();

        base.OnExit(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this particular case, in WPF app, there might be as well be no benefit.

Comment: For WPF I recommend designing a DbContext factory or using a UoW scope to manage DbContext scope where you want multiple classes to be able to be called and resolve the same DbContext instance rather than having an IoC provide it. For web applications with lifetime scopes of per-request, it is fine, but WPF form lifetime scopes are honestly too long for DbContexts. They get bunged up with tracked references or poisoned handling possible entry issues.

Comment: Thank you. Then it would look like the example with a new DbContext in a using block would be better after all. And if I take the UoW route, due to the lifetime scope of a WPF app, would it be a good idea to have the UoW class inherit from IDisposable and call Dispose on the context after it has been saved, or is that unnecessary? Providing the UoW class is not instantiated in a using block.

Answer (score 0):

The point of receiving an instance of `AppDbContext` in this case is that your `MainWindow` does not need to know the options that need to be passed along.

As you can see, when registering the `AppDbContext` with the dependency injection container, it configures the instance to be called with certain options, like the connection string to use with the SqlServer provider.

If you were to use `new` to produce an instance in the `MainWindow` directly, it would have to know how to pass these options along, which shouldn't be the concern of that class.

It's better to be able to configure this in your `App` class, which is your *composition root*, so that you don't need to repeat this knowledge in all of the classes that need an instance of `AppDbContext`, which would surely become a maintenance nightmare to keep track of.

In addition, I would like to mention that it's not a good idea to perform database operations inside a constructor. Constructors are for wiring up services, or initialising business objects, but it's a lot harder to deal with handling exceptions or performing asynchronous operations from a constructor.

Lastly, if you want to make sure that you're not keeping an active context around when your window isn't doing anything, it's a good idea to not inject the context itself but a *factory* that lets you instantiate a context whenever it is needed. It's a little bit more complicated to set up, but it's outside the scope of this topic.

Comment: Of course, now that I've written all this I also notice that you're passing the connection string in the `OnConfiguring` overload on the context itself. The problem is now that if you pass an options object for another reason, for instance performing a test, you're already overriding this from within the `OnConfiguring` method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The thing is, and this confuses me, I don't need to pass any options to the constructor of the AppDbContext class when I instantiate it. The options such as the Connection String are provided in the OnConfiguring method of the AppDbContext class and thus the benefit of using constructor injection must be very slim?

And thank you for pointing out that it is not good practice to implement database calls in the constructor. It was purely for instructive reasons though!

Comment: Well the connection string could come from configuration. So now your context class must be aware of where to get your configuration.

Comment: One benefit I can think of, is that putting the AppDbContext in the DI container allows me to also add another class by transient called for example IDbManager into the DI container. The implementation of IDbManager could then inject the AppDbContext in its constructor, and this would make it very easy to change DbManager without having to change the injected class (IDbManager) all over the code. But then I might as well just put the using block that creates a new instance of AppDbContext in the DbManager, and it would be the same thing...